# Meteor/Google Maps API: Make map zoom/position the same on all screens

Tags: google-maps-api-3, meteor

I got a reactive google map with markers and I want to use it on my home page. But on my small laptop I see just the world, no duplicates, but on a bigger screen the map repeats 3 times.

How can I prevent this?

Update: Basically, how do I lock the zoom, so if I zoom then page in and out the map looks the same (relatively)
I'm using: https://atmospherejs.com/dburles/google-maps

My Current HTML:

```
<template name="map">  
  <div class="map-container">
    {{> googleMap name="map" options=mapOptions}}
  </div>
</template>
```

My Current JS:

```
  mapOptions: function() {
    if (GoogleMaps.loaded()) {
      return {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(5, 0),
        mapTypeControl: false,
        scaleControl: false,
        navigationControl: false,
        scrollwheel: false,
        disableDefaultUI: true,
        draggable: false,
        zoom: 2,
        maxZoom: 2,
        minZoom: 2,
        scaleControl: false
      };
    }
  }
```

Comment: can you please paste the js and html code for review?

Comment: Also, please provide little more explanation of this sentence: *But on my small laptop I see just the world, no duplicates, but on a bigger screen the map repeats 3 times.* So by world you mean the basic map canvas and by map repeats 3 times, is it the whole window refreshing or just the map container?

Comment: @KayAnn basically. If I am on a small computer, I will see the normal map. But if I am on a really big one, I will see the whole word a couple times (So I will see about 6 international date lines).

Comment: How does your css styling looks like? Not sure if its maps container issue or Google Maps instance itself. So I guess you could try resize property of CSS and restrict the resize through initial or inherit. See if that helps out otherwise if its maps instance - there is view port biasing or setting max/min zoom levels.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like OP is too far zoomed out on large screens (mebbe 1200px+?), so map zoom level probably at say 2 or so.

sounds like what you want is to have zoom level change with screen size...; 
ie. if phone: zoom = 2, on iMac: zoom = 5 or something... IMO i would try to detect size then pass an if statement to the zoom option....

just trying to hopefully clarify. i've been working around by zooming in on a click event, per marker, and adding a small 'button' to zoom back out...